# The first console is shown to me, the last one does not. Any idea why?

Tags: react-native

The first console is shown to me, the last one does not. Any idea why?

```
async loginTwilio(name) {
    console.log("loginTwilio", name, "me escuchas");
    let log = new Log();
    let chatClientHelper = new ChatClientHelper(log);
    await chatClientHelper.login(
      name,
      FirebaseSupport.registerForPushCallback, 
      FirebaseSupport.showPushCallback
    );
    global.chatClientHelper = chatClientHelper;

    console.log("sali del login")
}
```

Comment: await chatClientHelper.login(name, FirebaseSupport.registerForPushCallback, FirebaseSupport.showPushCallback);
maybe this line doesn't get resolved and hence give a delay or error, try having a try catch block in your function

Comment: Agred with Sarmad, wrap your await call in try/catch, otherwise it will swallow errors silently

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will get better answers if you post your code as text. Other users are unlikely to assist you if they first have to transcribe your image.

Comment: Removed extra picture of code